# comparar resultado case

Tags: sql

Possuo uma tabela `customedio` tipo `numeric`, e quando o valor for menor que 0, quero que traga a mensagem "Valor negativo" e quando for `null`, no caso diferente de maior e menor que 0 traga "valor nulo".

Porém ao rodar o comando abaixo está dando o erro:

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "Negativo"

Acredito que é por que estou comparando um texto com campo numérico.

Como resolver?

```
select  pr.ean, upper(pr.nome) as nome, pr.unidademedida, se.quantidade, pr.customedioinicial,
(CASE  
when 
fpp.customedio>=0 then  fpp.customedio
when 
fpp.customedio<=0 then  'Negativo'

   else 'Valor nulo' end) as customedio, se.quantidade * pr.customedioinicial as Total

FROM produto PR
LEFT JOIN saldoestoque SE ON(pr.id=se.idproduto)
LEFT JOIN formacaoprecoproduto FPP ON(fpp.idproduto=pr.id)
 where se.quantidade is not  null   order by se.quantidade desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No PostgreSQL você poderia fazer:

```
SELECT pr.ean, upper(pr.nome) AS nome, pr.unidademedida, se.quantidade, pr.customedioinicial, 
 (CASE WHEN fpp.customedio>=0 THEN TO_CHAR(fpp.customedio, '99999') WHEN fpp.customedio<0 THEN 'Negativo' ELSE 'Valor nulo' END) AS customedio, 
 (se.quantidade * pr.customedioinicial)::TEXT AS Total
FROM produto PR LEFT JOIN saldoestoque se ON (pr.id=se.idproduto) 
                        LEFT JOIN formacaoprecoproduto fpp ON (fpp.idproduto=pr.id) 
WHERE se.quantidade IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY se.quantidade DESC;
```

Em outros SGBD você terá que utilizar a função de formatação adequada.

Comment: Esse comando não deu certo pois ele converteu as casas decimais do meu custo médio de 2.0000 para 2. isso seria um problema.  vou tentar resumir melhor meu comando.  Meu campo é NUMERIC   ele não ta aceitando eu digitar uma palavra.  select  (CASE

when (fpp.customedio>=0) then fpp.customedio
when (fpp.customedio<=0) then 'Negativo'
ELSE 'DIFERENTE' end) as customedio

FROM produto PR LEFT JOIN saldoestoque SE ON(pr.id=se.idproduto) LEFT JOIN formacaoprecoproduto FPP ON(fpp.idproduto=pr.id) where se.quantidade is not null order by se.quantidade desc

Comment: Eu entendi seu problema por isso a resposta foi para você converter seu número para uma string e aí seu campo de saída conteria apenas string, seja o número seja o texto alternativo. Para que seu número seja considerado com casa decimal utilize TO_CHAR(fpp.customedio, '99999.9999') utilizando a quantidade adequada de 9's de acordo com o conteúdo máximo de seu campo.

Comment: Entendi, cara muito obrigado pelo auxilio. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Descobri que no final devo converter o `customedio` em texto `::text`

```
select pr.ean, upper(pr.nome) as nome, pr.unidademedida, se.quantidade, pr.customedioinicial, (CASE
when (fpp.customedio>=0) then (fpp.customedio)::text
when (fpp.customedio<=0) then (fpp.customedio)::text
ELSE 'Não definido'::text end) as customedio, se.quantidade * pr.customedioinicial as Total

FROM produto PR LEFT JOIN saldoestoque SE ON(pr.id=se.idproduto) LEFT JOIN formacaoprecoproduto FPP ON(fpp.idproduto=pr.id) where se.quantidade is not null order by se.quantidade desc
```